# JAVA: returns a AbstractList which is filled but can't be seen were it is looped. Never seen programming style like this

Tags: java, list, fizzbuzz, qabstractlistmodel

This is the fastest solution for **FizzBuzz program** in leetcode(Question 412). I can't able to understand it line of execution and whats actually happening in program. Please help me out with explaining the line of execution of the program. Just tell me where the looping happens.

```
import java.util.AbstractList;

class Solution {
    public List<String> fizzBuzz(int n) {
        return new AbstractList<>() {
            @Override
            public String get(int i) {
                i++;
                if(i%15==0)
                    return "FizzBuzz";
                if(i%3==0)
                    return "Fizz";
                if(i%5==0)
                    return "Buzz";
                return i+"";
            }
            @Override
            public int size() {
                return n;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: looping happens outside of this code

Comment: The `fizzBuzz` method returns an instance of a subclass of `AbstractList`. The object behaves as a list but does not in fact store the list elements. Instead it calculates them on demand. A typical use would iterate through the “list” (so with a loop outside of this code as @IłyaBursov said) and print each element.

Comment: @OleV.V. can you please elaborate for me on not storing values.

Comment: Usually a list is a container for a finite amount of values in a defined order. The list class would then declare fields for those values and housekeeping. It could be an array for holding the values themselves and an `int` to tell us how much of the array is in use, for one example. So when asking for, say, item 5 of the list, the `get` method would look up in the array and return the element it had stored there. In the code you have posted there are no such instance variables. So the `get` method instead of retrieving the existing stored value computes it using the series of `if` statements.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is no looping.

They create a list which overrides methods.
Method `size` returns given `n` value.
Method `get` returns a string dependent on a given `i` value.
So, it means that they don't store values in a list - they just calculate value ("FizzBuzz"/"Fizz"/"Buzz") on a given index